# Команда chmod. Как ее запустить на платном сервере?

Tags: unix, сервер, linux

При работе на домашнем сервере проблем с командной строкой нету. Когда захожу через ftp или через встроенный в личном кабинете редактор нету возможности набрать команду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно зайти на сервер по ssh, тогда из терминала вы выполните команду chmod или любую другую, которая потребуется. Если сервер - это бесплатный или платный хостинг и нужно выставить права на файл, то многие хостеры дают возможность делать это из панели управления, надо немного поискать в настройках.

Сама команда chmod простая:

```
chmod 777 -R папка
```

добавит права на чтение, запись и исполнение папке и всему ее содержимому рекурсивно всем без исключения, а

```
chmod +x файл
```

добавит права на исполнение файлу. Обычно в Unix системах справка по команде показывается так: man команда (man chmod). На Ubuntu вроде часть справки переведена.

Если, например, к папке `download/files` нужно добавить доступ на чтение **всем**, то

```
chmod a+r download/files
```

Comment: Я искал долго -может плохо, но нашел другоеНаписать файл доступа    <?require "dostup.php";    ?>Но все равно, с этим вопросом хотелось бы разобраться. Я пыталсязапустить команду из TotalComander с командной строки при заходе на ftp. Не получилось.Как это делают другие на платных хостах?

Comment: У своего "провайдера" нашел инфу:Конфигурирование PHP через .htaccessНа веб-сервере Apache есть возможность управлять режимами работы папок. Для этого нужно поместить необходимые команды в файл с названием .htaccess и закачать этот файл в нужную папку на сервере.      php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on (пример)      С помощью подобных команд вы можете менять настройки PHP, которые иначе пришлось бы настраивать через php.iniЧто надо написать для запуска chmod в .htaccess и как потом запустить эту команду?И где искать файл php.ini?

Comment: UNIX / Apache - CGI    * через собственный конфигурационный файл, расположенный в .php/php.ini в корне вашего домашнего каталога;Но его там нету. Есть спецы по данному вопросу?

Comment: htaccess и chmod - совершенно не связанные между собой вещи. chmod - это команда unix, а htaccess - это файл настроек apache. Вам нужно узнать у своего хостера 1) есть ли доступ по ssh, есть ли в панель управления опции по изменению прав на файлы, либо то, либо другое должно быть на 100%.

Comment: Мне известно, что у меня есть доступ по SSH. Я так же могу иметь свой собственный php.ini. Так же имею право менять права доступа к файлам и папкам.Файл php.ini уже нашел. Могу подсказать как это можно сделать. Скачал putty для подключения через SSH. Но как установить права доступа к папкам пока не знаю. Все ключи для chmod мне известны.Пример: Надо к папке download/files установить доступ только чтение. Какую команду надо набрать?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Права для папок на сервере стоит устанавливать c кодом 755, а вот для файлов лучше ставить с кодом 644, для вашего случая: `chmod -R 755 /ПУТЬ/download/files/` и следом `chmod -R 644 /ПУТЬ/download/files/*.*`

Comment: Возможно    'chmod -R 644 /ПУТЬ/download/files/*.*'    не сработает для файлов в подпапках, то нужно сделать так:    'find /ПУТЬ/download/files/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {}'